# Plotting a simple 2D vector

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector

New to Python and just trying to accomplish what I think must be the simplest of tasks: plotting a basic 2D vector. However my online search has gotten me nowhere so I turn to stackoverflow with my very first question.

I Just want to plot a single 2D vector, let's call it my_vector. my_vector goes from (0,0) to (3,11).

What I have done is this:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
%pylab inline

x_cords = np.arange(4)
y_cords = np.linspace(0, 11, 4)
my_vector = vstack([x_cords, y_cords])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(my_vector)
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following image (and totally not what I am after):

[a very wrong plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39KLk.png)

However I have found that

```
ax.plot(x_cords, y_cords)
```

instead of

```
ax.plot(my_vector)
```

gives me the plot I am looking for but then I don't have that single vector I am after.

So how does one correctly plot a basic 2D vector? Thank you and sorry if this has indeed been posted somewhere else...

Comment: have you tried `hstack`ing your x and y co-ordinates?

Comment: yes but doesn't hstack just basically concatenate the x and y coordinates?

Comment: It does, but so does `vstack`, I was just wondering whether the shape of the array would affect it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also unpack your 2D vector

```
pl.plot(*my_vector)
```

Which is effectively just doing

```
pl.plot(x_cords, y_cords)
```

Comment: Could they also just do a line plot with two points ((0, 3) and (0,11))?

Comment: Thanks @CoryKramer!

Comment: One follow up question: how would one go about manipulating the style or color of the line when plotting it using '*'?

Comment: @keli You can specifically pass in keyword arguments (kwargs) by name, for example in this case `pl.plot.(*myvector, color='r', linestyle='--')`

Comment: @CoryKramer Thx!!